# JGit push won't fail when push is impossible

Tags: jgit

I'm trying to push a local repository to a github repository using JGit:

```java
String remote = "https://token@github.com/me/foo";
Repository repository = buildLocalRepository();
try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
  git.push()
      .setCredentialsProvider(new UsernamePasswordCredentialsProvider("token", ""))
      .setRemote(remote)
      .call();
}
```

But when the repository history on the remote is different (and consequently push is impossible) it neither fails nor touches the remote repository (fortunately). Any help?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you inspect the result returned by `call()`?

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann you're right. quick question: is this what I need to do? https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommandTest.java#L423

Comment: Link is broken, this is where you can find the sources:
https://git.eclipse.org/r/plugins/gitiles/jgit/jgit/+/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommandTest.java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're expecting an exception to be thrown; according to the Javadoc, rejected refs do not constitute an exception.  Instead, `PushCommand.call()` returns a list of `PushResult` objects, which you can inspect to see the status of each requested ref update.

Comment: Thanks. you're right. quick question: is this what I need to do? https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit.test/tst/org/eclipse/jgit/api/PushCommandTest.java#L423

Comment: The code looks plausible.  Your compiler and test suite can do a better job telling you if it's correct than I can.

Answer (score 1):

I found a [code snippet](https://github.com/jutzig/jabylon/blob/3ae465f5f15217d6f4d32da81925a7aad9bea09a/org.jabylon.team.git/src/main/java/org/jabylon/team/git/GitTeamProvider.java#L344-L353) that check the push results. It looks like this:

```java
/*
import org.eclipse.jgit.api.Git;
import org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.PushResult;
import org.eclipse.jgit.transport.RemoteRefUpdate;
*/

String remote = "https://token@github.com/me/foo";
Repository repository = buildLocalRepository();
try (Git git = new Git(repository)) {
    Iterable<PushResult> results = git.push().call();
    for (PushResult result : results) {
        for(RemoteRefUpdate update : result.getRemoteUpdates()) {
            if(update.getStatus() != RemoteRefUpdate.Status.OK && update.getStatus() != RemoteRefUpdate.Status.UP_TO_DATE) {
                String error = "Push failed: "+ update.getStatus();
                throw new RuntimeException(error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My [jbang script](https://gist.github.com/jmini/4e98dfa6d0a1860f63c21f587def2d2a) to test it.